# Decide which python version to use for pip and easy_install

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ipython, easy-install, python-2.4

I have two python versions on my server namely 2.4 and 2.7.  It is running RHEL 5.8.

I already have pip and easy_install installed on my server.

When I try to install ipython using easy_install or pip, it gives me an error which probably does not support in python 2.4.

I want to use python 2.7 for both pip and easy_install since I would want to use the latest version of the both.

What should I do to have pip and easy_install use python 2.7.  Python 2.4 is installed by default by the system and I do want to keep it.

Python 2.7 is installed at another location.

Below is the traceback both for easy_install and pip.  Both end up in the same error.  Any kind of help is appreciated.

PIP

```
ronak@ronak fun $ sudo pip install ipython
Downloading/unpacking ipython
  Downloading ipython-0.13.zip (6.4Mb): 6.4Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in ?
      File "/usr/local/home/ronak/fun/build/ipython/setup.py", line 23
        from __future__ import print_function
    SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in ?
  File "/usr/local/home/ronak/fun/build/ipython/setup.py", line 23
    from __future__ import print_function
SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/ronak/.pip/pip.log
```

EASY_INSTALL:

```
ronak@ronak $ sudo easy_install ipython
Searching for ipython
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ipython/
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org/dist
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/0.8.4
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/0.9.1
Reading http://ipython.org
Reading http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.12.1
Reading https://github.com/ipython/ipython/downloads
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/old/0.9
Reading http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/0.10
Reading http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.11/
Reading http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.12
Best match: ipython 0.13
Downloading https://github.com/downloads/ipython/ipython/ipython-0.13.zip
Processing ipython-0.13.zip
Running ipython-0.13/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-vgPLN2/ipython-0.13/egg-dist-tmp-GHUgsq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/core.py", line 149, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 946, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 61, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 23
    from __future__ import print_function
SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

1. Open pip/easy_install in text editor
2. Check top line, it should say

   #! /usr/bin/python
3. Change it to #!path/to/python2.7

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions).

You may also want to consider using virtual environment through `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` to manage which version of Python your packages should use.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to easily install iPython, SciPy, MatPlotLib, etc. by downloading a .dmg, you can try here:

http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

Or if you have a academic email address:

http://www.enthought.com/products/edudownload.php

Comment: From the error messages, the OP is on some Linux distribution and not a mac.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /location/to/python2.7 /path/to/pip install ipython`

If you have a recent version of pip, you an also try `sudo pip-2.7 install ipython`